# Recommendations for a free iPhone photo editing app?

Tags: gratis, photography, image-editor, iphone-app

Just looking to do very basic stuff. Adjust brightness, write/type on a photo, that kinda stuff.  I hate going to those clicky-linky sites because it always takes you in circles while making money off your clicks.  :oP

I'm not a pro, just looking for something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Snapseed which is available for both [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapseed/id439438619?mt=8) and [Andorid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed&hl=en) is a great option. It rivals many paid options in features, but is very simple to use as well.

Some features include:

- Crop/Rotate
- Brightness/Saturation/Contrast/Tone
- Selective adjustments
- Filters
- Vignette
- HDR effect

In the most recent version, they have added additional support around layers and the ability to "undo" changes. But if you aren't interested in more complex editing such as this you do not need to utilize it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Adobe Photoshop Express](http://www.photoshop.com/products/photoshopexpress)

It the best software for editing images. And it is free.

It lets touch-up images, share them conviniently, and capture images right from the app.
You can download it form [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235?mt=8&ls=1)